# Make redirect to new url but remove previous from history

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, http-redirect

How to replaces the current URL document with a new one but removes the URL of the current document from the document history, meaning that it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate back to the original document and not store in browser history list.

I can to this by jQuery or javascript by

```
  window.location.replace("newURL");
```

but I need to do like this in php.HOW?

Comment: What do you mean "from PHP"?  Do you mean when the initial page is loaded, you want to redirect with no remnants of the original page in browser history?  Or do you mean from an ajax call?

Comment: when the initial page is loaded  i want to redirect with no remnants of the original page in browser history

Comment: I think a simple 302 redirect will do what you want.  The original URL will not be in the back button list, but it will be in the history list (for purposes of keeping track of "visited" links).  This should be how all browsers work.

Comment: i wanna also not to be in history list because this page used for control that i do not want anyone to know about it

Comment: Don't think you can do that.  If the user enters a URL into the browser or clicks on that link, it will be in the history.  If you don't want URL parameters in the history, then use a form POST because form contents are not in the history.  Besides, if it's a clickable link that the user did in the first place, you're kind of fooling yourself to think it's a secret.

Comment: Or, do your server-side work via an Ajax call and then nothing will be in the history and after the ajax call, do `window.location.replace(...)` in the client to go to your new page.

Comment: give example in answer section to remark it as the right answer but do not forget the example because i don not know lot of thing in ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want no remnants of the page in the browser history at all, then you cannot send the browser there because it will keep track of all visited pages in the history so it can properly show which links have been visited.  As best as I know, there is no way to stop the browser from keeping track of the visited links.  If you do a 302 location redirect from the server, both original and redirected page will be in the browser history.  The original page will not be in the back-button list, but will be in the history.

If the part of the URL that you are trying to keep less visible is query parameters to the URL, then you can use a form post instead of regular page load because the browser will not store form parameters in the visible part of the history.

Otherwise, you may need to use your URL with an Ajax call (since that will not be stored in the history) and then use client-side `window.location.replace(...)` to go to the final URL, the idea being that the URL you don't want to share publicly will have never been an URL that the browser page went to, only a URL that was used for an Ajax call.

Comment: Even if OP makes it an AJAX request, the user can still see the URL in the Network tab of Developer Tools in the browser. He can _never_ truly hide a URL a user's browser interacts with.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `<?php header('Location: http://www.abc.de/'); ?>` on the page http://www.something.de/ then the page http://www.something.de/ will not be visible in the browsing history nor can the user navigate back. Is this what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
<button onclick="goBack()"></button>
```

```
<script>
        function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
            window.location.replace('url');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to clear your previous page, try to use "history.back();" and then set your windows.location.